# String method with array of integers

Tags: java

Please help with code. I have tried adding substring, etc, to remove the end comma. How can I do this?
Example: `{1,2,3}` to string is now `"1,2,3,"`

```java
public static String arrayToString(int[] numbers) 
{
  String stringify = "";
  for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) 
  {
    stringify = numbers[index] + ", ";
  }
  return stringify;
}
```

Comment: return stringify.substring(0,stringify.length - 1)

Comment: You also might want to think about using a StringBuilder

Answer (score 2):

### Best way

Delete the entire method. Use `Arrays.toString(int[])` instead. Why rewrite core functionality like this?

### Stream way

```
return Arrays.stream(numbers)
  .boxed()
  .map(String::valueOf)
  .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

### StringBuilder way

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0) out.append(", ");
    out.append(numbers[i]);
}
return out.toString();
```

Adding to a string in a loop is bad form (it wastes a ton of memory), so don't do that. The above strategies are in rough order of preference, with the top option miles ahead of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your method to the following one:

```
public static String arrayToString(int[] numbers) 
{
  String stringify = "";
  for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) 
  {
    stringify = numbers[index];
    if (index < numbers.length - 1) {
        stringify += ", ";
    }
  }
  return stringify;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to view this as having a separator **before** every number except for the first.  Or, equally, that there's a separator before **every** number, but the first separator is empty.

```
public static String arrayToString(int[] numbers) 
{
  String separator = "";
  String stringify = "";
  for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) 
  {
    stringify += separator + numbers[index];
    separator = ", "
  }
  return stringify;
}
```

Note, I fixed the assignment to `stringify` to be `+=` rather than `=`, since otherwise you're just getting the last number.

In practice, I'd probably use a StringBuilder, but I wanted to leave this as close to the original as possible.  With a StringBuilder, the same separator technique can be used.